# Why does dynamic fail to invoke methods on my dynamicly built object?

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have a type that I build with `TypeBuilder` to match an interface, like this::

```
interface IFoo
{
     int Property{get;}
}
```

My code builds the get_Property method. If I cast my built object as an IFoo, everything works. However, when I use the object as a dynamic the the code complains that my IFoo does not implement get_Property. Why is this happening, can I not use the dynamic functionality with types built at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dynamic` uses the public API. If you are using `TypeBuilder` it is possible that you have *just* provided a method and marked it as implementing that method, in which case it is (essentially) an explicit interface implementation, and undiscoverable by `dynamic`. To use `dynamic` it would probably need `PropertyBuilder` and a public property, with the property implementation method *also* marked as the interface implementation.

For comparison, `dynamic` would also fail with:

```
class Foo : IFoo {
    int IFoo.Property { get {return 5;}}
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast response! That's pretty damn lame though. I guess I have to do some more work on my duck taper. I guess its really hard to force C# into being a dynamic language.